# Combine Tables Given Date Criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I'm trying to combine to two tables, and I want the smallest id where the date from one table is greater than the date from another table.  I think this is an easy task, but it's giving me a fit.

Here was my naive attempt:

```
select table1.id, MIN(table2.id)

FROM table1
   INNER JOIN table2
     ON table2.id = table1.id

WHERE table1.date > table2.date
```

This doesn't work, because once the date in table1 is greater than table2 it joins all the ids not just the ones greater than the date.  Meaning that it returns the smallest id no matter what.

Thanks

EDIT FOR CLARITY:

Product

```
id | price_date
---------------
 1 | 2011-01-02
```

Price

```
id | fid | price_date
---------------
 1 |  1  | 2011-01-01
 2 |  1  | 2012-01-01
```

So I want to return

```
product.id | price.id
---------------------
    1      |   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really like this, seems a bit brute force. But is that the kind of result you are looking for?

EDIT to match sample data:

```
select id AS product_id
      ,(select min(id)
          from price
          where fid = p.id
            and price_date <= p.price_date
       ) AS price_id
  from product p
```

EDIT2: With the sample data showing the fk relation, Nikola's response is a better solution:

```
select p.id AS product_id
      ,MIN(x.id) AS price_id
  from product p
      ,price x
  where x.fid = p.id
    and x.price_date <= p.price_date
  group by p.id
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but it essentially gives me the same thing, but instead is functioning as a left outer join instead of my inner join.

Comment: @tshauck Could you put a couple of rows sample data with the expected result? I think this is a bit different from your attempt in that the query here is executed for each record in table1 (which is the part I don't like) whereas the attempt in the question is joining ids between the two tables. (ie the join is in the "select" list, not the "from" list.

Comment: @tshauck and assuming fid is foreign key to product.id

Comment: I'll give you the check because I like this answer for what I asked and you were first.

But the question was malformed for what I wanted which is my fault, but I got it.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for.

```
select table1.id, 
       table1.date, 
       MIN(table2.date) Table2MinDate, 
       MIN(table2.id) Table2SmallestID
FROM table1
   INNER JOIN table2
     ON table1.date < table2.date
group by table1.id, table1.date
order by 1, 2
```

I strongly believe that there should be a join condition between table1 and table2, but it could not be id because asking for minimal id from table2 would not make sense. It would always have the same value as id from table1.

[You might check Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff925/1)

Comment: @Nikola_Markonvinovic I was thinking along this line as well, but with a cross product originally. But now, with the sample data, I think it becomes more clear: the join is on product.id and price.fid. Then I this  is clearly the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand quite what you are trying to achieve - I am assuming that you want to return the min() for table2 for each row in table1 where table1.date > table2.date.  In this case, you could use a sub-select:

```
SELECT table1.id, (SELECT min(id) FROM table2 WHERE table1.date > table2.date) 
FROM table1
   INNER JOIN table2
     ON table2.id = table1.id AND table1.date > table2.date
```